# How to replace only one character in a string in Dart?

Tags: string, dart, flutter

I am trying to replace only one character in a string dart but can not find any efficient way of doing that. As string is not array in Dart I can't access the character directly by index and there is no function coming in-built which can do that. What is the efficient way of doing that?

Currently I am doing that like below:

```
List<String> bedStatus = currentBedStatus.split("");
   bedStatus[index]='1';
   String bedStatusFinal="";
   for(int i=0;i<bedStatus.length;i++){
      bedStatusFinal+=bedStatus[i];
   }
}
```

index is an **int** and **currentBedStatus** is the **string** I am trying to manipulate.

Answer (score 31):

**Replace at particular index:**

As `String` in dart is **immutable** [refer](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/String-class.html), we cannot edit something like

```
stringInstance.setCharAt(index, newChar)
```

**Efficient way** to meet the requirement would be:

```
String hello = "hello";
String hEllo = hello.substring(0, 1) + "E" + hello.substring(2);
print(hEllo); // prints hEllo
```

Moving into a **function**:

```
String replaceCharAt(String oldString, int index, String newChar) {
  return oldString.substring(0, index) + newChar + oldString.substring(index + 1);
}
replaceCharAt("hello", 1, "E") //usage
```

*Note:* `index` in the above function is *zero based*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it wont work as pattern here matters. Your code will replace 0011 to 1011 irrespective of the supplied index which is not what I want.

Comment: So u want to replace the char at given index?

Comment: yes. as we do in java with **myName.setCharAt(4, '1')**

Comment: I updated my answer. We don't have `setCharAt` in Java as String is immutable there also

Comment: extension StringExtensions on String{

  String replaceCharAt({required int index, required String newChar}) {
    return substring(0, index) + newChar + substring(index + 1);
  }  
}

Answer (score 23):

You can use `replaceFirst()`.

```
final myString = 'hello hello';
final replaced = myString.replaceFirst(RegExp('e'), '*');  // h*llo hello
```

Or if you don't want to replace the first one you can use a start index:

```
final myString = 'hello hello';
final startIndex = 2;
final replaced = myString.replaceFirst(RegExp('e'), '*', startIndex);  // hello h*llo
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use **replaceAll().**

```
String string = 'string';
final letter='i';
final newLetter='a';
string = string.replaceAll(letter, newLetter);  // strang
```

Answer (score 5):

with this line you can replace the `$` symbol with a blank space ''

```
'${double.parse (_priced.toString (). replaceAll (' \ $ ',' ')) ?? '\ $ 0.00'}'
```

```
String x = _with.price.toString (). ReplaceAll ('\ $', '')) ?? '\ $ 0.00',
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use this in build function to do it.

```
s.replaceRange(start, end, newString)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String.replaceRange](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.5/dart-core/String/replaceRange.html) to replace a single character of a string given a **start** and **end** index.

The method declaration looks like this:

```
String replaceRange(int start, int? end, String replacement)
```

So given the string `"hello"` and you'd want to replace `"e"` with `"a"`, call:

```
"hello".replaceRange(1, 2, "a")
```

So `1` is the index at `"e"` and `2` is the index after that and the result is `"hallo"`.

You could make a function to replace a single character like this:

```
String replaceCharAt(String text, int index, String replacement) {
  return text.replaceRange(index, index + 1, replacement);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do

```
  final singleChar = 'a';
  final characters = yourString.characters.toList();
  characters[index] = singleChar;
  yourString = characters.join('');
```

Here is how it would look like in a String extension method

```
  String replaceCharAt({required String char, required int index}) {
    final chars = characters.toList();
    chars[index] = char;
    return chars.join('');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function, just modified Dinesh's answer

```
      String _replaceCharAt(
          {required String character,
          required int index,
          required String oldString}) {
        if (oldString.isEmpty) {
          return character;
        } else if (index == oldString.length) {
          return oldString.substring(0, index) + character;
        } else if (index > oldString.length) {
          throw RangeError('index value is out of range');
        }
    
        return oldString.substring(0, index) +
            character +
            oldString.substring(index + 1);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use substrings and not worry about chars.
Create substrings from string and use indices.

```
String ourString = "OK_AY"; // original string - length of 5
String oldChar = "_"; // the character we wanna find and replace - as type string - in this case, an underscore
String newChar = "X" // the char we wanna replace underscore with
int index = ourString.indexOf(oldChar, 0); // find the index in string where our char exists (may not exist)

//some logic here to return or skip next code if char wasn't found

//oldChar found at index 0 (beginning of string)
if (index == 0) {
    ourString = newChar + ourString.substring(index+1, ourString.length);
}

//oldChar found at index 4 (end of string)
else if (index == str.length-1) {
      ourString = ourString.substring(0, index) + newChar;
}

//oldChar found anywhere else between
else {
      ourString = ourString.substring(0, index) + newChar + ourString.substring(index+1, ourString.length);
}

//done, ourString is now updated "OKXAY"
```